# Where are my Office 2011 AutoRecovery files?

Tags: macos, microsoft-office

I have followed the following suggestion [that was posted on here](https://superuser.com/questions/516140/excel-2011-mac-auto-recover-file-lost) but it says "The folder can't be found".

The path that was suggested is: `/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office/Office 2011 AutoRecovery`

Can someone please help? I am desperate.

> As the /Users/username/Library folder is a hidden folder since OS X 10.7 and not by default searched by Spotlight it's incredibly stupid that this folder is auto-suggested when saving a recovered file.
>
> Also since there IS a folder with the same name under Documents/Microsoft userdata/ that is empty this was hard to find!
>
> To go to this folder, open Finder and in the menu click Go » Go to Folder… or press ⇧⌘G. Then, paste the path from above.

Comment: Have you changed `username` to your actual short name, e.g. `johann`? Or even better, try `~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office/Office 2011 AutoRecovery`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get to your hidden user library directory.

Switch to the "**Finder**" and hold down the "Option" key and select "**Go**" in the *Menu Bar* up top and you will see "**Library**" listed.

Select this item and from there you can navigate the path provided to you in the previous post.